# Is it possible to use same struct for gorm as well as json?

Tags: go, struct

```
type Student struct {
     name string `gorm:"fullname"` `json:"student_name"`
}
```

Will this work?
Is this allowed?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: *"Is it possible to use same struct for gorm as well as json?"* -- Yes, just keep in mind that for both gorm and json your fields *must* be exported, i.e. they must start with an uppercase letter, e.g. `name string` is unexported, `Name string` is exported.

Comment: You will need to put them both in the same set of backticks, ie `gorm:"fullname" json:"student_name"`

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem, it is allowed as gorm and json use different tag name

Answer (score 0):

**Delivery data types and entity data types are highly recommended to be kept separate.**
*But can you do it?* Yes. *Does it work?* Yes. *Is it quick solution?* Absolutely

Here is some question to answer if it is needed to be kept in one struct :

1. What happens if you add additional field to your data model?
2. Are others developers warned about this decision?
3. Are you okay with later time consuming refactoring?

But correct way to do it in my opinion is to separate models and convert them using mapper function.